# Is this the limit of list inception?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am a student in the process of learning Python and I 
was interested in finding out the extent of how many lists you can keep on implementing inside the newly created lists. In one word, the extent of limitception...
So, I decided to find out myself and after a period of copying and pasting with accuracy, I managed to find it out with proof that's shown below.

```
listception = [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[["NINETY TWO"]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]

print(listception[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0])

print(len("[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]"))

print("276/3 = " + str(276/3)) #since '[0]' is 3 characters

print(len("[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[["))
```

The o/p came out to be this:

NINETY TWO

276

276/3 = 92.0

92﻿

Adding any more square brackets in the list results in stack overflow error (lol)

So is the limit 92? (Btw, I did this in Python 3.7, don't know if that matters.)

Comment: Try `more_listception = [listception]`, you'll be amazed. I'll write an answer if I got time.

Comment: This is a limit of the parser for list-literals, not a limit on lists objects.

Comment: If you're interested in nested lists, something fun to play with is a recursive list. Try `lst = []; lst.append(lst)`.

Comment: I see! I didn't think about approaching it from other ways. I'll try them out later. Thanks all!